# How to you make data validation go through?

Tags: c++, validation

When testing my output, there's one part (the red circled part) that I'm having trouble with.

When the input starts with numbers and then letters, it goes through (ex. `45Gge`). After, the program ends, skipping the part where it asks if they want to do it again.

When the input starts with letters and/or numbers, the validation fails loop works (ex. `gsdf` or `ggs52`). Does anyone know why it allows for numbers then letters to go through?

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    float fee = 0.0;
    float hours = 0.0;
    float minFee = 2.50;
    char choice;
    
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed;
    
    do
    {
        std::cout << "Enter parking hours: ";
        std::cin >> hours;
        
        while(std::cin.fail())
        {
            std::cout << "\nIncorrect Input! Numbers Only.\nTry Again.";
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    
            std::cout << "\n\nEnter parking hours: ";
            std::cin >> hours;
        }
        
        if(hours <= 3)
        {
            fee = minFee;
        }
        else if(hours > 3 && hours < 24)
        {
            fee = (((hours - 3) * 1) + minFee);
        }
        else
        {
            fee = 20.00;
        }
        
        std::cout << "\nTotal Cost: $" << fee;
        
        std::cout << "\n\nWould you like to pay another fee? (Y or N): ";
        std::cin >> choice;
        
        while(choice != 'y' && choice != 'n')
        {
            std::cout << "\nIncorrect Input! \"Y\" or \"N\" Only.\nTry Again.";
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    
            std::cout << "\n\nWould you like to pay another fee? (Y or N): ";
            std::cin >> choice;
        }
        
    }while(choice == 'y');
        
    std::cout << "\nThankyou for your payment." << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

I want the circled part to validate the data.

Comment: Recommendation: Almost no one is going to look at the image and there will be many who simply can't see the image for one reason or another, so mark the region of interest in the example code with some highly visible comments.

Comment: Instead of trying to read in a float, read the line (or a string) and then check its content. If you read in a float it reads until it encounters a character that isn't legal in a float. So 45G validly reads a 45 and leaves the G in the input buffer for the next input.

Comment: `hours` is a `float`.  So `std::cin >> hours` will read characters until it reaches a character that can not be part of the `float`.  You seem to be confused about what `std::cin >> hours` actually does.  If you enter `0`, followed by the complete works of Shakespere, the `0` will be read as the `float` and the rest will not be read, until you try reading more.